# TPL Dataflow block with an inner life

Tags: tpl-dataflow

I've been doing a bit of TPL dataflow coding and am quite happy with the basics. The question I have is, how would I go about doing a TPL block that, besides reacting to its queue, also has a life on its own?

Like, a background task that runs on a permanent loop, polling the odd webservice or database every few seconds and emitting messages on its outputs when it sees fit?

The interface would be a source- and target block, but with no apparent connection between source messages and target messages.

Basically an "active" block.

Comment: A dataflow block that is both an `ITargetBlock<T>` and an `ISourceBlock<T>` needs someone to feed it with messages, and also someone to consume the messages it produces. Otherwise 1. will have no work to do, or 2. will consume all the memory of the machine by its ever growing internal output queue. So I am not sure about what usage you have in mind. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Something that /doesn't/ necessarily need an input via TPL. As I wrote, an example would be a service that polls a data source, like, once per second, if it gets a result, sends it on to its successor TPL block, and maybe listens to an input where a message could tell the block to poll a different url, for instance.

Comment: So you are talking about blocks that are not linked formally via the [`LinkTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.linkto) method, and instead they communicate informally by [sending messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.post) to each other?

Comment: They are linked formally, they just send messages temporally independent from possible inputs.

Comment: Hmm, your question currently is too abstract IMHO. My suggestion is to include a specific example in the question, composed by a minimal number of dataflow blocks, explain how these blocks interact with each other, and ask a specific question about the scenario at hand.

Comment: @Volker dataflow blocks don't work that way. They aren't background tasks or workers. A background worker/service/whatever can have a loop that triggers a dataflow pipeline, not the other way around. You can create a timer to ping a TransformBlock to trigger it. Or you could create a TransformManyBlock that contains a loop with `Task.Delay` that yields a dummy object or a URL to trigger a poll. That doesn't make the block a background service though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, here's what I did in the end:
My FSM class consisted of a broadcast block, working as input, a bufferblock working as output and an async method with an endless loop running in the threadpool. The async method gets the current input value from the broadcastblock whenever needed, does its thing and posts a result to the bufferblock, in my case every second.

A user of that FSM class can link to the broadcast block's input and the bufferblock's output. The async method polls the input when needed and gets new values. Whatever it does, the result goes to the buffer block.

The interface then looks like

```
public interface IFsmBlock : IAsyncDisposable
{
    ITargetBlock<string?> SearchParameterInputPort { get; }
    ISourceBlock<string> FoundEntriesOutputPort { get; }
}
```

With possibly more than one input or output block. In this instance, the FSM treats the input port basically as a variable containing a value. If the input port should trigger something, that's easily possible by using an action block instead of the buffer block.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks aren't background tasks or workers. They don't have a lifetime of their own outside the pipeline and their messages. That doesn't mean you can't do what you ask though. You'll have to somehow trigger the head block from the outside though.

One way to do what you want is to create a timer that "pings" the head block of a pipeline:

```
var head=new TransformBlock<int,...>(...);
...
var timer=new System.Threading.Timer(_=>head.PostAsync(0),null,0,5000);
```

You can start, stop or change the timer as needed.

You could use this eg to process the files in a folder periodically :

```
var crawler=new TransformManyBlock<string,string>(root=>{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(root,"*.csv");
});
var parseCsv=new TransformBlock<string,Record[]>(filePath=>{
    var records=await parseCsvAsync(filePath);
    return records;
}
...
var timer=new System.Threading.Timer(_=>head.PostAsync(rootFolder),null,0,5000);
```

Comment: `var timer` -- The timer should be rooted, not just assigned to a variable in the stack, because `Timer`s [don't have a life of their own](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27654 "Proposal: Timer static Create methods that make rooting behavior explicit").